# How do you change the log level of Paypal's java sdk

Tags: paypal

I have an existing integration with Paypal using the java sdk. We're planning a production release, but we can't let it got to prod with the current log level of the sdk. It seems to be set to DEBUG and logs every request going/coming from Paypal. I guess there must be a parameter to add to the paypal_sdk_config.properties file, but I can't seem to guess it and documentation is inexistant on the matter.

Anyone has ever done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just discovered, going through the code source of the com.paypal.core.LoggingManager class, that the logger creation is not intuitive.

The logger name is always something like **class**  for example: **class com.paypal.core.APIService**

It means that you cannot set the log level through this call

```
getLogger("com.paypal.core.APIService").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

To set the log level, you need to do that:

```
getLogger("class com.paypal.core.APIService").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

I just open an issue on the Paypal github repo for that strange behavior: https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/issues/13